# Appengine server-to-server authentication and Google Domain-wide Authority

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to pull my reports from YouTube reporting API and upload them into GCS. Since I must use oauth2, I used Google's guide on creating a service account and giving it domain-wide authority. While I can get authenticated service to pull the reports at user level. I get "The caller does not have permission" when appengine runs the request. Any idea where to look next?

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics-monetary.readonly',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner-content-owner-readonly',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_write']
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'file.json'
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
delegated_credentials = credentials.with_subject('email@email.com')
storage_client = build('storage', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
youtube_reporting = build('youtubereporting', 'v1', 
credentials=credentials)
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/b93f87cfaa0115e5_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test-project-67412/20180712t103610.411083715789214207/main.py", line 66, in get
    jobs = list_jobs(youtube_reporting, ContentOwner, True)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test-project-67412/20180712t103610.411083715789214207/main.py", line 52, in list_jobs
    includeSystemManaged=True).execute()
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test-project-67412/20180712t103610.411083715789214207/lib/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~test-project-67412/20180712t103610.411083715789214207/lib/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://youtubereporting.googleapis.com/v1/jobs?onBehalfOfContentOwner=ContentOwner&alt=json&includeSystemManaged=true returned "The caller does not have permission">
```

--UPDATE--
So I guess it had to do with Domain-wide authority for service account. I deleted the account, created a new one, gave it domain-wide authority, and it works just fine now.

Comment: `While I can get authenticated service to pull the data at user level` - you mean you can run this successfully locally, on your machine?

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I meant, I can successfully run the request locally in a python script using oauth2 user level authentication.

Comment: Where exactly did you get the error? On `storage_client ` ? Can you post a traceback?

Comment: Sure, I added the traceback. I get the error at YouTube Reporting API call.

Answer (score 0):

--UPDATE-- So I guess it had to do with Domain-wide authority for service account. I deleted the account, created a new one, gave it domain-wide authority, and it works just fine now.
Read the main file. and replace the coded

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).